# Resetear todos los inputs que estén dentro de un div en una nodeList

Tags: javascript

quería saber como podría hacer para limpiar los inputs de un nodeList siempre y cuando tengan la clase "div"

[image: El nodeList en cuestión]

Probé esto y muchas cosas más pero nada, no estaria encontrando la forma:

```
let nodoHijos = clon.childNodes;
nodoHijos.getElementsByTagName("div").querySelector("input").value = "";
```

Lo que tengo en el HTML es lo siguiente:

```
<div class="row clonar">
    <div class="col mb-2">
        <input class="form-control form-control-sm" id="input1" type="text" aria-label=".form-control-sm example" placeholder="Nombre y Apellido" name="NyA1" required>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <input class="form-control form-control-sm" id="input2" type="text" aria-label=".form-control-sm example" placeholder="Cohorte" name="Cohorte1" required>
        </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
            <input class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" type="text" placeholder="Correo Institucional" name="CorreoInstitucional1" required>
            <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon2">@hotmail.com</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <input class="form-control form-control-sm" id="inputGroupFile02" type="file" name="FotoAlumno1" required>
    </div>
</div>
```

Y el script es este:

```
<script>
    let agregar = document.getElementById("agregar");
    let contenido = document.getElementById("contenedor");

    agregar.addEventListener("click", e =>{
        e.preventDefault();
        let clonado = document.querySelector(".clonar"); // Seleccionamos lo que vamos a clonar
        let clon = clonado.cloneNode(true); // Ya clonado el nodo, osea el div

        let nodoHijos = clon.childNodes;
        // Obtener todos los inputs
        let inputs = nodoHijos.querySelectorAll('div input');
        // Recorrer para poner valor
        inputs.forEach(input => input.value = '');

        contenido.appendChild(inputs).classList.remove("clonar"); // Adjuntamos un hijo al final de todo
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Podrás subir el código html para hacer pruebas? Necesitas seleccionar y borrar los input dentro de las etiquetas div o dentro de otras etiquetas con clase "div" porque en tu código nunca seleccionas una clase. Si nos pasas el código será fácil poder ayudarte.

Comment: Si, ya agregúe el codigo HTMLy el JS también por las dudas, gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás usando `querySelector`, que devuelve solo un nodo. Usa `querySelectorAll()` para obtener todos los que coincidan y, de paso, simplifica con un selector CSS que especifica que los input deben estar dentro de un div, eliminando la necesidad de `getElementsByTagName()`.

Finalmente, recorre los inputs en un ciclo para poner el valor como cadena vacía:

```
// Obtener todos los inputs
let inputs = clon.querySelectorAll('div input');
// Recorrer para poner valor
inputs.forEach(input => input.value = '');
```

Comment: Me dice lo siguiente en la consola: Uncaught TypeError: nodoHijos.querySelectorAll is not a function

Comment: @MarceloSanchez, cierto, `.childNodes` devuelve una colección y no se puede usar ahí `.querySelectorAll()`, basta con obtener los inputs directamente del elemento clonado. Revisa la respuesta, acabo de editarla.

Comment: Me funcionó, muchas gracias :D